# Accessing a field in csh

Tags: csh

This piece of code:

```
foreach mod ("`lsmod`")
   echo $mod
end
```

outputs each line of `lsmod`. How can I access the first field, i.e. Module, from each line?

Is there any IDE for`csh` or extension for vs code where I can debug `csh` code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach mod ("`lsmod`")
   set ml = ($mod)
   echo "$ml[1]"
end
```

Comment: Parentheses splits line with any type of delimiter or only space?

Comment: An unquoted variable will be split on any kind of whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines), but multiple newlines will not be collapsed into a single separator.

Comment: I've another [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530516/how-to-split-and-access-fields-delimited-by-colon) on accessing fields