# How to split and access fields delimited by colon?

Tags: tcsh, csh

This piece of code:

```
foreach line (`cat /etc/group`)
    echo $line
end
```

returns `line` containing 4 fields delimited by `:`.

How to split fields and access the first field of each `line`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach line ("`cat /etc/group`")
    set fs = ($line:gas/:/ /)
    set f = ($fs)
    echo "$f[1]"
end
```

In `tcsh` you can omit the intermediate `fs` variable, and directly `set f = ($line:gas/:/ /)`.

The `:s/pat/rpl/` variable modifier will replace every occurrence of `pat` in the variable with `rpl` (`pat` is a simple text, no regexps are recognized). The `a` flag tells to replace all occurrences, and the `g` flag to do it in all the words.

If using the original `csh` and the `/etc/group` file contains glob metacharacters, you'll have to bracket the loop in a `set noglob` / `unset noglob` pair.

Comment: what's `gas` and why there's an extra slash in `gas/:/ /`

Comment: looks like I've to have a space before the last slash, Is there any online doc to know more about these tricks of `csh/tcsh`?

Comment: They're in the csh(1) manpage, all those modifiers are described under the "History substitutions" section, since they're similar.

Comment: So it's like `g` for global, `a` for all and `s` for substitute, nice!

Answer (score 0):

Use awk with the `-F` flag.  You'll have to use echo and pipe into awk like so:

```
for line in `cat /etc/group`
do
   col1=$(echo $line | awk -F':' '{print $1}')
   col2=$(echo $line | awk -F':' '{print $2}')

   # Then you can use col1, col2, etc...

   echo "column 1 = $col1"
   echo "column 2 =  $col2"
done
```

Comment: I'm looking for a `csh/tcsh` based solution to this like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529988/accessing-a-field-in-csh).

Comment: ahh, unfortunately bash is my specialty, apologies

Comment: It's alright, hope this answer would help someone else to solve his/her problem

Comment: That's not even correct Bash/sh syntax (you're missing the `in` keyword). Even if you correct that, running `for line in $(cat file)` is just a bad way to do it and only works in this case since `/etc/group` has little whitespace apart from the newlines.

Comment: Agreed.  Reading files in this way is a pain in bash.  Fixed in answer that isn't correct in any case